# Android Dynamic button the button to be erased - Got the Solution

Tags: android, button

Lastbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  - Solution.

And i am trying some maths calculation like below.

```
     4     2   8    3                   ( Displayed in Button )

     +     -   *    /                   ( Displayed in Button )
```

Suppose if the user presses 4 then + then 2  then like below. (1st pressed button to be removed)

```
          6    8   3
```

Suppose if the user presses 6 then * then 3  then like below. (1st pressed button to be removed)

```
               8  18
```

Suppose if the user presses 18 then -  then 8  then like below.

```
               10
```

I tried and its not working. And i am pasting my current version of the code also.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lm);

        // Create a LinearLayout for each row inside the outer LinearLayout.
        LinearLayout firstRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        firstRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        // Create a String array of items you want to add to the inner LinearLayout.
        String[] itemsToAddToFirstRow = { "4", "2", "8", "3"};
        createButtonsDynamically(firstRow, itemsToAddToFirstRow);

        String[] itemsToAddToSecondRow = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
        LinearLayout secondRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        secondRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        createButtonsDynamically(secondRow, itemsToAddToSecondRow);
    }

    private void createButtonsDynamically(LinearLayout layoutToAddButtonsTo, String[] itemsToAdd) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToAdd.length; i++) {
            final Button buttonToAdd = new Button(this);
            buttonToAdd.setText(itemsToAdd[i]);
            buttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Strvalue = (String) buttonToAdd.getText();
                    operation(buttonToAdd);   
                }
            });
            layoutToAddButtonsTo.addView(buttonToAdd);
        }

        // In the end add all buttons inside the inner LinearLayout to the outer LinearLayout.
        lm.addView(layoutToAddButtonsTo);
    }

private void operation(Button buttonToAdd)
   {
       if (Strvalue.equals("Clear"))
       {
           buttonToAdd.setEnabled(true);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was clicked: " + Strvalue , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else
       {       
       if (Strvalue.equals("+") || Strvalue.equals("-") || Strvalue.equals("*")|| Strvalue.equals("/"))
       {
          flag = true; 
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was clicked: " + Strvalue , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Pressoperator = Strvalue;
          product1.setText("Calc Answer:  "+ Calctotal);
       }
       else
       {  
           flag = false;
           if (Pressoperator.equalsIgnoreCase(Emptystr))
           {    
               Calctotal = Integer.parseInt(Strvalue);
               Prevvalue = Integer.parseInt(Strvalue);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was clicked: " + Calctotal , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               product1.setText(Integer.toString(Calctotal));
           }
           else
           {  
               if (Pressoperator.equals("+")) { Calctotal = Prevvalue + Integer.parseInt(Strvalue); }
               if (Pressoperator.equals("-")) { Calctotal = Prevvalue - Integer.parseInt(Strvalue); }
               if (Pressoperator.equals("*")) { Calctotal = Prevvalue * Integer.parseInt(Strvalue); }
               if (Pressoperator.equals("/")) { Calctotal = Prevvalue / Integer.parseInt(Strvalue); }
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was clicked: " + Calctotal , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Prevvalue = Calctotal;
               product1.setText(Integer.toString(Calctotal));
           }
           if (Calctotal == total)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Yureka Your Answer is Correct " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
           }
        }
       } 

   }
```

Comment: `I tried and its not working.` Can you clarify a bit more on what it actually did?

Comment: i tried to removeview() the button, but it forcefully abending.  Not sure why.